# Check if a layout exists in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

Is there a standard way to check if a view layout exists from within a Controller in Rails?  I'm trying to allow the user to determine the layout, but it needs to exist first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard public way as far as I know.  You could use a rudimentary call like this:

```
layouts = Dir['app/views/layouts/*'].map {|f|
  File.basename(f, '.html.erb')  # returns 'layout' for 'layout.html.erb'
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Although clearly not perfect it is in fact a valid answer

Comment: Yes, this worked better for me than the template_exists? below.

Answer (score 25):

You can use template_exists? which is an alias for [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths/exists%3F)

For example: `template_exists?("layout_name", "layouts")`

Comment: Your comment definitely pointed me (who has the same question as the OP) in the right direction. exists? (and template_exists?) are methods in ActionView::LookupContext (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb). I want to use them from my ApplicationController. Is that too early? Is the current LookupContext already set? How can I access it from my ApplicationController?

Comment: I should do a search before posting questions. LookupContext is initialized in AbstractController::ViewPaths and can be accessed plainly as lookup_context in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way would be store these values in a database, let a user choose from that.

Instead of trying to verify through what has been suggested in the previous post.

Use a Layout Model and let the user choose.